# Add class selected relative URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a **highlight** class selected to my category:

This is my code :

```
<div id="category">
    <ul>
        <a href="category.php?c=electronic">
            <li>Electronic</li>
        </a>
        <a href="category.php?c=fashion">
            <li>Fashion</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selected {border-bottom:3px solid red; }
```

Script:

```
$("#category ul a").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.href){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }     
});
```

When I click on electronic category, it will show highlight class **.selected**, but, the problem came up when the **URL page change** into category.php?c=electronic&page=2

Highlight class .selected not showing anymore, how to modify this jQuery, so, it will show again? I found JavaScript **split URL** article, is it work for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead.

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
var windowURL = window.location.href;

if (windowURL.indexOf(url) != -1){
  $(this).addClass("selected");
}
```

```js
$("#category ul a").each(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("href");
  var windowURL = "category.php?c=electronic&page=2";
  console.log(windowURL, url, windowURL.indexOf(url)); // <--- see how the values change

  if (windowURL.indexOf(url) != -1) {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }

});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="category">
  <ul>
    <a href="category.php?c=electronic">
      <li>Electronic</li>
    </a>
    <a href="category.php?c=fashion">
      <li>Fashion</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG! thanks you so much Mr. Dhiraj! your solution very very simple and working so fast as hell! YOU DA REAL MVP!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.indexof()** function to check the string is exist in url or not

Here i have update your code:

```js
$("#category ul a").each(function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) > -1){
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }     
});
```

```css
.selected {border-bottom:3px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="category">
    <ul>
        <a href="category.php?c=electronic">
            <li>Electronic</li>
        </a>
        <a href="category.php?c=fashion">
            <li>Fashion</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This one also Working! thanks you so much Mr. Bhavin!! God Bless you!